# How do I use different crossAxisAlignment for different rows on the same column?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to align two pieces of text differently, where each piece of text is in a different row but in the same column.

Here's a crudely illustrated structure for this widget

[image]

As you can see "info text" is next to "video duration", but I want it at the top, and I want to keep "video duration" at the bottom at all times.

I tried using alignment settings but I don't know why one doesn't seem to be working (I commented it in the code below)

```
class MiniVideoCell extends StatelessWidget {
  final lesson;

  MiniVideoCell(this.lesson);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(

                children: <Widget>[
                  new Image.network(
                    lesson.imageUrl,
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //meant to align elements to the left - seems to be working
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //trying to bring this text up, not working
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("info text"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text("video duration"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set your `mainAxisAlignment` property of your Column widget to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. This would put all available space between your Row widgets.

```
new Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //meant to align elements to the left - seems to be working
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Add this line
    children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //trying to bring this text up, not working
            children: <Widget>[
                new Text("info text"),
                ],
              ),
        new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
                new Text("video duration"),
                ],
        ),
    ],
)
```

And also we need to specify the `height` and `width` of our Container widget like this:

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    width: double.infinity, // Added width 
    height: 124.0, // Set your preferred height
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
...
```

Output would look like this:

[image]

Here is the partial code:

```
Column(
      children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            width: double.infinity, // Added this 
            height: 124.0, // Set your preferred height
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children:[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 150.0,
                      height: 100.0, // Assuming that the height of the thumbnail is 100 pixels
                      )
                  ]
                  ),

                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Place all available space between the children
                    children:[

                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //trying to bring this text up, not working
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("info text"),
                          ],
                        ),

                       Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, //trying to bring this text up, not working
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("video duration"),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ]
                    )
              ]
              ),
            ),

          Divider(),
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I've been trying for hours and a lot of the times mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment settings don't seem to do anything at all

Comment: your answer helps a lot, but I was getting text overflow on the right because the title was too long. What I did to fix was using a Flexible widget with Column as its child. Then inside of column instead of using Row I used a Wrap widget with Axis.horizontal direction. https://pastebin.com/viw897Mm **does it look ok to you?** I couldn't make it work without wrapping everything inside a Flexible widget.